# When saving parent entity in EF, is the child entity also persisted in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When saving a parent entity in EF, is the child entity also persisted ?

I have something like this:

```
Public Class Property
{
      public virtual ICollection<ImageSortOrder> Property_ImageSortOrders { get; set; }
}
```

When I am saving `Property`, I am also populating `Property_ImageSortOrders`. Would that also save `Property_ImageSortOrders`?

Comment: yes it should save the child data as well if changes were made

Comment: It saves the child data.
When updating and you don't won't to override - remember to include record